# Difference between libraries and how to include them

Tags: c, shared-libraries, static-libraries, codeblocks, libraries

I am developing a C code that should be portable under Linux and Windows using codeBlocks.
I should include the NetCDF C libraries and the HDF5 libraries.

Evidently, libraries in linux are .so and .a sometimes. In windows, whether .lib or .dll.
What are the differences between them and which one should I use? I used the .so under linux and it's working but I would like to know why it should work.

Second question is that I include the files netcdf.h and hdf5.h
The paths are not the same .../lib/netcdf.h in linux and ..\lib\netcdf.h
Although I know I can change the links every time I toggle between windows and linux, but I am sure there should be a way to avoid that without file duplication in the source code.

Could anyone please let me know how to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is two (mostly unrelated) questions. This is not good.

Comment: Also *libraries* are linked, not "*include*"d.

Comment: The issue is that I should add a link to the library netcdf.a or .so or .bib or .ddl and a link to the include file .h in the same project. That is why I asked all in the same question :). Thanks for your understanding :).

Comment: the easiest method is to use a make file.  The make file would contain a #ifdef (what ever is used to recognize windows) ...windows version of the compile/link statements #endif followed by #ifdef (what ever is used to recognize linux) ... linux version of the compile/link statements

Answer (score 1):

Executables (PE in Windows, ELF in Linux), Static libraries, Shared libraries can have the same code
the main difference is the way they're compiled and the way they're going to be loaded into memory (execution)

".a" in Linux and ".lib" in Windows do the same job, called static libraries, static libraries are only needed in compile time, when you use a function from a static library, the function code is being copied to your resulted executable, so you do need the full library while running the executable, which result in a larger executable than using shared libraries.

".so" in Linux and ".dll" in Windows, are also the same, the difference from static libraries is that their functions aren't copied to your executable, they're only pointed to in the executable, so you'll need the actually library near the executable in runtime

The second question isn't really a problem, you can use both "/" and "\" on Windows, but if it happens to be an issue you can use ifdef switches:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
//Windows based code
#include <windows_headers.h>
#elif __linux
//Linux based code
#include <linux_headers.h>
#else
#endif
```

P.S: You can use ifdef switch anywhere in your code that has platform differences

Comment: Thank you Marware for you useful answer. Regards.